# Adding string to variable adds "\" in javascript onkey function

Tags: javascript, php, string-concatenation

I am relatively new to php and to javascript , I know I am making some silly mistake. However, my question is if I add string to variable it adds "\" before ' this.
my Javascript function :

```
$('#search_name').keyup(function(){
  var search1 = $(this).val();

   search1="and user_name like '%"+search1+"%'";//Concatenate string

  if(search1 != '')
  {
    load_data(search1);

  }
  else
  {
    load_data();   
  }
});
```

And I have a load_data function which url is fetch_user.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 load_data();
 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
  url:"fetch_user.php",
  method:"post",
  data:{query:query},
  success:function(data)
  {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
});
}
```

Now on my fetch_user.php I am echoing concatenated string and it adds "\"

```
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["query"]);
 echo $search; 
}
```

Output is `and user_name like \'%k%\'`
rather it should be `and user_name like '%k%'`
So, what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: It's that `mysqli_real_escape_string` doing that I bet.

Comment: I have further sql query to run  so that line is necessary too, isnt it?

Comment: You should really redesign this as it is bad practice to pass SQL strings from client to server like that. It is an open door to SQL injection.

Comment: Do not do this. Someone can take that javascript and have it submit bad data for SQL injection. Instead, pass in the username via the javascript, and have PHP add it into the query properly.

Answer (score 1):

The mysqli_real_escape_string function escapes all quotes by adding a /.

You should however never build the query in Javascript and pass that to php. In stead only pass the search string through POST.

You can than build the query in MySQL and pass the variable to MySQL.

Comment: build it in PHP you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Since mysqli_real_escape_string adds escape character (i.e. **/**) to quotes, instead of sending the part of where clause through ajax, you should post only the `search1` value.

```
$('#search_name').keyup(function(){
  var search1 = $(this).val();

  if(search1 != '')
  {
    load_data(search1);

  }
  else
  {
    load_data();   
  }
});
```

In PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["query"])){
 $search = "and user_name like '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['query'])."%'";
 echo $search; 
}
```